# REQUEST param gives error due to .htaccess file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a hard time getting my .htaccess correct. I'm using codeigniter MVC.

Below is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /webappl

  # Reenable after getting ssl cert
  # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Removes access to the system folder by users
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  # When your application folder isn't in the system folder This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the request to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I'm using codeigniter MVC. I have complete mvc under `website.com/webappl`. And .htcaccess file is also in `website.com/webappl` directory.

`$_REQUEST` parameter doesn't work. When a do `print_r($_REQUEST)` at url `website.com/webappl/prof?parm1=value1&parm2=valu2` it gives output:

```
Array ( [/prof] => [PHPSESSID] => 20b15a4c76eddd60ec208f422b4047b1 )
```

But it should return

```
Array ( [parm1] => value1, [parm2] => valu2);
```

I don't know where it is going wrong.

Comment: remove `?` in `/index.php?/$1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Working fine for my applications.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /webappl/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Note the change to RewriteBase **/webappl/**